# Validate a multi select input field in HTML using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a select input field in multiple properties. I have to validate (empty check) this field in both JavaScript and PHP. My code is like:

```
select multiple="multiple" name="frm_supply[]>
```

Comment: Cannot help unless you give us some validation rules?

Comment: Refer this stack overflow answer [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697401/how-to-validate-group-of-select-items-in-javascript/13697718#13697718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an HTML code like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="frm_supply[]">
  <option value="s1v1">A</option>
  <option value="s1v2">B</option>
  <option value="s1v3">C</option>
</select>
<select multiple="multiple" name="frm_supply[]">
  <option value="s2v1">1</option>
  <option value="s2v2">2</option>
  <option value="s2v3">3</option>
</select>
```

When submitting the form, if A, B and 1 are checked, `$_POST` array will be like this:

```
Array (
  [frm_supply] => Array (
    [0] => s1v1
    [1] => s1v2
    [2] => s2v1
    )
  )
```

So, check trough a loop if any <select/> is empty. The following code walks through two <select/>s and displays for each either *"List N has values"* or *"List N is empty"*.

```
$countValuesPerList = array();
foreach ($_POST['frm_supply'] as $key => $value)
{
  $index = substr($value, 1, strpos($value, 'v') - 1);
  $countValuesPerList[$index] = true;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
  echo isset($countValuesPerList[$i]) && $countValuesPerList[$i] ? 'List ' . $i . ' has values' : 'List ' . $i . ' is empty';
}
```

Now, to check selections on client side, proceed the same way [and check what is selected in each <select/>](http://www.digitalamit.com/blog/blog/23.html).

Answer (score 0):

multiple selection values are stored in a array .
so check  the length of the array and according to ur validation rule, for example for atleast 2 selection ,the length of the array should be greater than 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="name">
   <?php
   for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      echo '<option value='$i'>$i</option>';
   }   
   ?>
</select>
```