# How to validate group of select items in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There are about 6-7 `<select>` items in a `<table>` column. In order to press `Submit` button, the condition is all `<select>` items should be selected. So how this can be done using Javascript..?

The sample code seems to be like this:

```
         <table>
 <tr>
    <td><select name="name1" style="width: 90px; height: 20px"> 
                            <option value = "--" >--</option>
                <option value = "10" >10</option>
         </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><select name="name2" style="width: 90px; height: 20px">
                            <option value = "--" >--</option> 
                <option value = "20" >20</option>
                </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><select name="name3" style="width: 90px; height: 20px"> 
                            <option value = "--" >--</option>
                <option value = "30" >30</option>
                </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="name1" style="width: 90px; height: 20px">
        <option value = "--" >--</option>
        <option value = "10" >10</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="name2" style="width: 90px; height: 20px">
        <option value = "--" >--</option>
        <option value = "20" >20</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="name3" style="width: 90px; height: 20px">
        <option value = "--" >--</option>
        <option value = "30" >30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="if(!check()) return false;">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
  elements=document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("select");
  for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    if(elements[i].value == "--") { return false; }
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), then add "required" to all your select fields.

```
<form id="my_form">
    <select name="select1" class="required"> ... </select>
    <select name="select2" class="required"> ... </select>
    <select name="select3" class="required"> ... </select>
    ....
</form>
```

Then the javascript is as simple as -

```
$('#my_form').validate();
```

All you need to do to use the plugin is include the jQuery and jQuery validation scripts in the page head

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    ....
</head>
```

UPDATE

Obviously your requirement is a pretty simple one, and adding a full js library to your site for this use case is definitely over-kill. If this is the only validation you're going to do I'd recommend a pure js solution (such as polin's answer). However if you're likely to have further validation requirements on your site, then the jQuery validation plugin is quite powerful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to use it less myself - you end up writing stuff that should really be pure js.

Answer (score -1):

```
       var arr=new Array();
   status=true;
   function fnc()
   {
       elements=document.getElementById("atable").getElementsByTagName("option");
       for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
       {
           arr=elements[i].value;
           if(Number(arr)=='NaN')
            {
                status=false;
                break;
            }

           console.log(Number(arr));
    }
    if(status==true)
    document.getElementById("formname").submit();
    }
```

you also give your table an id

```
<table id="atable">
```